# Sum of same cells in consecutive sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I have multiple sheets and similar data in the same cells in all the sheets. How can I add this data without naming all the sheets separately?

```
=SUM(A!C4, B!C4, C!C4, D!C4)
```

Instead of doing the above I want to name Sheet A and D and everything in between. Is this possible?

In Excel I can use this:

```
=SUM('FIRST SHEET:FINAL SHEET'!G45)
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, this is not possible in Google Sheets (without script).

in Google Sheets, all cells/ranges need to be properly referenced